# Converting Attachements to Files - App on the AppExchange

Tags: attachment, files

[image]

As we all know that going forward Salesforce is going to remove the Attachments and would require all Attachments to be converted into 'Files'.

However, I am unable to find this Option to convert Attachments to Files in my Dev Org. Can someone tell me where do I "Enable" this feature?
Note: I am using an old Dev Org.Please refer to the screen shot - Shared by an MVP on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of the Convert Attachments to Files app. You can install the managed package from my GitHub project https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files

The [README](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/blob/master/README.md) document has instructions with screen shots and links to other documentation how to enable all recommended options. There is even a FAQ at bottom of that page to answer common questions regarding the conversion process.

If you run into any problems, you may [open an issue](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/issues).

Answer (score 4):

You can enable this from following screen.

Type General Settings in Quick find box

[image]

Ref url : http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_files_notes_attachments_list.htm

Comment: awesome..... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the blog which details about the attachment to file migration.

https://techevangel.com/2018/05/01/how-to-convert-attachments-to-files-in-salesforce/#more-230